# Write Cypher query to display temperature values till it reaches set temperature

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have about 200,000 rows of 24 hour data as follows:

[image: initial data]

I can use the query to create a room node with time, roomtemp, and set temp as properties. Moreover, I can also, define the relationship of each room with its corresponding temperatures.

Now, I need to find:

1. all rows  that show an update/increase/decrease from initial temperature till set temperature for all rooms. e.g. based on above data, I need:

[image: result]

Here I have discarded 5th row data as 16 was repetitive and showed no update(increase or decrease) in temp value. The temperature values continued till it reached set temperature '18'.

I can manually create the temperature states by giving its values one by one, but I am unsure how to MERGE the above requirement into the graph using Cypher.

2. Can I utilize any other programming language to obtain same results using Neo4j in conjunction?
3. Do I have to utilize in-graph time-tree for this scenario? Can I retrieve my results without creating a time tree?

Comment: At first sight I would question your use of Neo for this type of data. The data appears more tabular than heavily relationship based. SQL databases are very good at this. Is it part of a bigger application which is has a high number of relationships?

Comment: @Duff - Just curious why you couldn't embed images (see my edits - I fixed it for you; has nothing to do with available privileges).

Comment: @joe - this question wasn't a debate on which database to use. No need to argue for SQL database - that just turns this into a discussion/debate.

Comment: @Duff - What do you mean by "utilize any other programming language"? There's no code shown here, just data and query requirements. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: **@ joe:**
I have over 50+ properties for each relationship. Its kind of easier to understand data in that way. 

    **@ David:**
Thank you so much for editing. Actually I tried to embed image, unless I have 10 reputation, I can not embed any image, due to rules set by Stack OF.  Probably to avoid posting in-appropriate images here by new users.
Actually I tried Cypher to write my requirement code, but I failed. Probably, cz I am just a beginner .Then I thought that perhaps there is a possibility to write same requirement in another programming language using Neo4j platform

Answer (score 0):

1. Filter temparature by room and date (which can also be a date-node)
2. Sort by time
3. Collect into a list
4. Filter by differences in two subsequent temperatues
5. Turn list into rows

Here is a query that does this:

```
MATCH (r:Room)<-[:TEMP]-(t:Temparature)
WHERE t.time STARTS WITH "2016-01-01" 
AND t.temp < room.temp ADN t.temp > {initial}
WITH t ORDER by t.time ASC
WITH collect(t) temps
WITH [idx in range(0,size(temps)-2) WHERE temps[idx].temp <> temps[idx+1].temp | temps[idx] ] as filtered
UNWIND filtered as t
RETURN t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Appreciate it a lot. I was not expecting a reply from you. Thank you. Though, I have two requests:" WITH [idx in range(0,size(temps)-2) WHERE temps[idx].temp <> temps[idx+1].temp | temps[idx] ] as filtered  "
1. Can you please break it down in to a general syntax, so that I am able to fully understand it and manipulate it later for other queries.
2. I need to understand, what is the best scenario to use a timetree in- graphs or linked lists; and that writing query in Cypher is a much better option than writing same code in another language in Neo4j (if that is possible)?

Comment: What is the difference between t.temp and setTemp? Is it the same? 
I am using LOAD CSV command to MERGE data.  In that case,  my initial query looks like:

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/Users/... room.csv" AS n
MERGE (r:Room{time:n.Time,roomName: n.Room, roomTemp:n. RoomTemp, setTemp:n.SetTemp});

Can you please alter you query. It is a little confusing for me.

Do I have to make separate room and temperature nodes?
i.e.
MERGE (r:Room{time:n.Time,roomName: n.Room, roomtemp:n. RoomTemp,setTemp:n.SetTemp})
MERGE (t:Temperature{time:n.Time, roomtemp:n. RoomTemp,setTemp:n.SetTemp});

Comment: I tried this code, however, this code has syntax error. 

Esp.: {initial} needs to be defined as it is a  parameter

AND t.temp < room.temp ADN t.temp > {initial}

// here room.temp should be r.temp

WITH [idx in range(0,size(temps)-2) WHERE temps[idx].temp <> temps[idx+1].temp

// here I am having syntax error with  temps[idx].temp and temps[idx+1].temp as .temp is undefined

I need to ask this "t" node has roomTemp or setTemp or both?